# Merge Excel cells in php

Tags: php, excel

I am writing a php file to export a report in Excel format and everything is working fine except the formatting ,

I have to merge some cells but I don't know how to do it

```
//header
$data = 'header1'.'\t'.'header2'.'\t'.'header3'.'\n';
//bodt    
foreach($orders as $order){
   $data .= 'data1'.'\t'.'data2'.'\t'.'data3'.'\n';
}
//footer
$data .= 'total'.'\t\t'.'\n';
```

I want to merge the cell "TOTAL" with the next 8 cells , how to do that ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its better you add a comment instead of devote and just run ??

Comment: Your post needs more details to be answered as well :)

Comment: I have added example to what I want to do, I hope its more clear now

Comment: What library are you using to work with the Excel file in PHP?

Comment: I am using PHPExcel @NicholasHunter